# Salesforce Lightning createRecord Open the Popup and Suddenly Close

Tags: lightning

I am trying to modify the behavior of Default "New" button on Opportunity tab on Salesforce Lightning Experience. (My requirement is to open the create record popup with some pre-filled values)

I created a Lightning component

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride" >
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.myEvent}" value="{!this}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Here is the Controller code

```
({
    myEvent : function(component, event, helper) {

        var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        createRecordEvent.setParams({
            "entityApiName": "Opportunity",
            "defaultFieldValues": {
                "Name" : "TestOpportunity",
            }
        });

        createRecordEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

Then I overridden the default New button behavior to Lightning component bundle.

When I click the New button on opportunity tab, it open the create record popup and suddenly close. Before it close, I can see that the default field value also set. But why it suddenly close automatically? Appreciate your help.

Comment: I have just tried the same in my sandbox - on a custom object and it works fine. please try on a different object, maybe something on your opportunity is interfering.

Comment: Hi @ItaiShmida, Thanks a lot for your reply. I created a brand new Developer Org and tested the above mentioned code. It is working fine. But in my old Org, problem exists. Anyway thanks for the support.